# Keycloak Token Exchange refresh_token requested_token_type unsupported

Tags: keycloak, impersonation, keycloak-rest-api

I am using token_exchange to impersonate as another user in the same realm. This endpoint works fine for access_token retrieval. However since  the access token will expire after sometime, I would like to also have refresh token so that I can refresh it when access_token would expire.

```
curl --location --request POST 'https://localhost:8080/auth/realms/demo/protocol/openid-connect/token' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
--data-urlencode 'grant_type=urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:token-exchange' \
--data-urlencode 'client_id=democlient1' \
--data-urlencode 'requested_subject=3784f93a-fc2a-48c6-9641-3abb27724b06' \
--data-urlencode 'subject_token=xxxxx' \
--data-urlencode 'requested_token_type=urn:ietf:params:oauth:token-type:refersh_token'
```

When I set requested_token_type=urn:ietf:params:oauth:token-type:access_token it is working. I am getting the access_token and expires values.

As per https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak-documentation/blob/master/securing_apps/topics/token-exchange/token-exchange.adoc this documentation, I can get refresh_token, access_token and id_token.

Not sure why this is unsupported. Keycloak version is 11.0.3

Comment: I'm getting the same for id_token :(

Comment: Same issue with id_token. But strangely I can get both access_token and refresh_token.

Comment: Don't know if this would matter but you have refresh_token spelled refersh_token in your question.

Answer (score 0):

For the issue on the id_token, found that this was a case of incorrect [documentation](https://keycloak.discourse.group/t/token-exchange-retrieve-id-token-fails/12211).

But the hack they suggest works, which is to set the scope to "openId" if you want an id_token and leave the requested token to access_token.

Answer (score 0):

Is democlient1 a public client? My requests for impersonation always need a client secret.
The logs on the server help a lot if you activate DEBUG logging for

```
org.keycloak.protocol.oidc
org.keycloak.services.managers.AuthenticationManager
```